# Comparison of arrays in google apps script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, comparison

I have the 2 below lists:

```
array_main = [[01-0158969,315],[01-0161045,699],[01-0161046,500]]
array_helper_both = [[01-0158969,315],[01-0161045,699],[01-0161050,500]]
```

I am trying to compare array_main with array_helper_both and if there are any differences (elements PRESENT in array_main but not in array_helper_both), then I am trying to add it to array_helper_both. For example, "01-0161046" is in array_main but not in array_helper_both.

Hence array_helper_both result would be:

```
[[01-0158969,315],[01-0161045,699],[01-0161050,500],[01-0161046,500]]
```

This is the code I tried but doesn't seem to work:

```
var list3 = array_helper_both.filter(x => !array_main.includes(x));
var list4 = array_helper_both.concat(array_main.filter(x => !array_helper_both.includes(x)));
```

Any leads/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is would work if they were flat arrays. But they are 2D-arrays. You can't compare two 2D-arrays as if they are just 1D-array and some values `if (some_array.includes(some_value))`.

Probably you could in this case turn the inner arays into flat strings:

`[01-0158969,315]` --> `"01-0158969,315"`

To compare the values, and then turn the values back into arrays:

`"01-0158969,315"` --> `[01-0158969,315]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare two arrays (elements in `array_main` and in `array_help_both`). The simplest option would be to use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var array_helper_both_string = array_helper_both.map(val => JSON.stringify(val));
var list4 = array_helper_both.concat(array_main.filter(x => !array_helper_both_string.includes(JSON.stringify(x))));
```

See the following thread for possible (and probably better) alternatives:

- [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)